Will program use SVE can auto adapt to wider SVE register set?
If i write a program which use SVE instructions, and compile it in a ARM platform which support 256bit width SVE register set.Then copy the executable file to a ARM platform which support 512bits width SVE reigter set, will the program automatic adapt to use 512bits operations rather than 256bits operations?
If it can how it works.

SVE provides tools that allows developers to write vector-length agnostic code. There are built-in intrinsics that let you query the vector length at runtime, so you can use that to increment loop counters or address offsets by whatever the actual SIMD width is. There are special vector types that will be stack allocated at the right size at runtime.
It isn't a magic solution, developers need to write code that is compatible with the vector-length agnostic style or it won't work. It's definitely possible to write SVE code that only works on a single vector length and, if you know the vector length, it may be more efficient to do so.
